# using AMA reference style while using the achemso.sty

Tags: bibliographies

I've written a paper for the AIChE Journal, but using the achemso.sty, given that this journal does not provide with a style file. 
Now that the article is finished and approved, the editor is asking me to use the AMA reference style. 
After re-searching the web for a correct .sty for the journal I'm submitting to (AIChE Journal) I couldn't find none. And I could not set achemso.sty to use the AMA reference style. I've found ama.sty and aichej.sty, but I dont know how to override the achemso.sty in order to access such styles.
In this sense, I've tried to use the command \bibliographystyle{ama} but I've got errors when generating the references file.
Has anyone tried to do something similar? does anybody know how to set up the AMA reference style in achemso? 
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Well, `achemso` is really intended for a particular task! However, there are ways to achieve what you want:

```
\let\LaTeXbibliographystyle\bibliographystyle
\def\bibliographystyle#1{}
\usepackage{achemso}
\let\bibliographystyle\LaTeXbibliographystyle
\bibliographystyle{ama}
```

This will save the original definition of `\bibliographystyle` and restore it after loading `achemso`.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the following:

http://www.elsevier.com/framework_authors/misc/model6-num-names.bst

I have tried it and according to myself, it is indeed the AMA style. I had a *hard* time finding it. I have not yet checked if it is the "no et al." version but that does not trouble me, since that is easy to modify in the `.bst` file.

Use it with

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This `bst` style requires some package such as `natbib` to work, so I have added that to the above code.

Comment: The link above is dead. A copy can be found at http://www.math.pitt.edu/~troy/ed/ed2/model6-num-names.bst

Answer (score 0):

I had to comply with the AIChE journal standards recently as well. I was using the achmso template on sharelatex, which meant that I could not easily make direct edits to the underlying bst file etc.

Using the following commands I was able to comply with the journal style

`\setkeys{acs}{articletitle = true} //turn on article titles
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literature Cited} //rename references section
\renewcommand*{\bibnumfmt}[1]{#1} //remove parenthesis around numbers
\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{n}{}{} //ibid`